# Why the IOS-API posting an photo on facebook page post on my own page?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, post, photo

I used below codes to post photo on Facebook PAGE not my own page.

```
 [FBRequestConnection
      startWithGraphPath:@"/PAGE_ID/photos"
      parameters:self.postParams
      HTTPMethod:@"POST"
```

but, after requesting this, the photo uploaded on my own page not PAGE_ID's wall.

I don't understand.. I just followed this, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos

but the result is not I'm expected.. :(

Comment: Is the account that you signed in with, one that owns that page?

Comment: yes. is it problem?, when I tested it by javascript api in web, it worked as expected..

Comment: no, that was my thought for why it might not work.

Answer (score 1):

Post using the Page access token, not the user's access token -

The discrepancy you've noted here (that the specified object (page) is ignored in favour of the access token owner (user) is a known issue and is due to be resolved in the next few months as far as I know

Comment: Thank you for your Answer
but, I want to anyone can post photos on page.
how to get page access token by user who not me ?

there are two methods to get page accesstoken, but both seem not work..
1. me/accounts : clearly, it's not other's page.
2. /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the manage_pages : is return just page ID..